# Express React Router and Middleware

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-dom

I have a server/website that is using express and react. I'd like to serve the website using `app.use(express.static())`. This is working the way I'd like to except it is interfering with a single server handled url `/parse-dashboard` which is served as a separate middleware.

```
const path = require( 'path' )
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var url = require('url');

var app = express();

var config = require( path.join( __dirname, 'config' ) )
app.use('/parse-dashboard', ParseDashboard(config.dashboard, true));

// Middleware for reading request body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));

app.set( 'port', process.env.PORT || 3000 )

const server = require( 'http' ).createServer( app )
server.listen( app.get( 'port' ), () => {
  console.log('express server listening on port ' + ( process.env.PORT || server.address().port ));
});
```

When I go to `/parse-dashboard`, the React app (which is using `react-router-dom`) takes the url and shows a blank route. How can I have this route be shown by the server instead?

Comment: what do you mean by "blank route"? your react app is not getting mounted to the dom?

Comment: By that I mean the react router is taking the route for itself even though I have no `Route` assigned to that url. It just shows my base page with no content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and boy do I feel dumb. In the React app folder contained inside my server(Express) folder I have a `package.json` file to declare the React dependencies. The `package.json` file still had the `proxy` key contained in it that some guides have mentioned to use in order to get api calls to your own server to go through when working locally. After removing that key it all works as expected, `/parse-dashboard` is handled by express and the rest are handled by `react-router-dom`